# Knockout.js - How to create a custom bindingHandler similar to 'with'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to make a custom bindingHandler, something like `data-bind="withSmartForm: formModel"`.

But despite all the other functionality I want it to behave like `with`, so the current context changes to formModel, and I can access the subproperties like `data-bind="value: email"`.

I know there are workarounds like always prefixing the subproperties with formModel, or put a `with: formModel` in a parent element, but as I will be using this pattern a lot I'd like to keep it as short as possible.

In the following fiddle I'd like to merge the `with` and `withSmartForm` into one bindingHandler.

http://jsfiddle.net/k89Fg/1/

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update: working example**

http://jsfiddle.net/k89Fg/4/ - thanks to Andrew Walters for the winning answer!

Comment: What have you done yet ? Can we see a fiddle ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is described in the docs here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html

From the docs:
*Bindings such as with and foreach create extra levels in the binding context hierarchy. This means that their descendants can access data at outer levels by using $parent, $parents, $root, or $parentContext.
If you want to do this in custom bindings, then instead of using bindingContext.extend(), use bindingContext.createChildContext(someData).*

Example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withProperties = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with a extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var newProperties = valueAccessor(),
            childBindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(viewModel);
        ko.utils.extend(childBindingContext, newProperties);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(childBindingContext, element);

        // Also tell KO *not* to bind the descendants itself, otherwise they will be bound twice
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```